# C# database writing to table doesn't work

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem using Visual Studio 2010. I am using a service-based database (`.mdf`). 
I have created a table manually in Visual Studio with some information. The code I have written can read from the table but when I insert new information it looks like the data is added to some other database.

I can read information from the correct table but when I add information to the table I can’t see the changes in Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

I don't know why to different databases are used! Does anybody know the problem?

Here is my code:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private SqlConnection sqlConnection;
    private SqlCommand sqlCommand;
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapterAnimal;
    private DataSet dataset;
    private string connectionString = DBAccessLayer.Properties.Settings.Default.AnimalDBConnectionString;

    public DataSet LoadAnimalDataSet()
    {
        dataset = new DataSet();

        using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            dataAdapterAnimal = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM AnimalTable", sqlConnection);
            dataAdapterAnimal.Fill(dataset, "AnimalTable");
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return dataset;
        }
    }

    public void AddAnimal(int animalID, string name, double age, string category, string gender, string extraAnimalInfo)
    {

        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AnimalTable VALUES(@AnimalID, @Name, @Age, @Category, @Gender, @ExtraAnimalInfo)", sqlConnection);

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AnimalID", animalID));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", name));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Age", age));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", category));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", gender));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExtraAnimalInfo", extraAnimalInfo));
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us some code you have tried.

Comment: Is there any exception? Are you sure that there is no triggers in that table?

Comment: Most likely, you are reading from 2 different databases. VS will make a copy of an .mdf for you in your project/solution. Is this the case?

Comment: I have only created one database. But I do have in my project solution a database created also.

Comment: Can you show us your connection string? Are you using a `AttachDbFileName=....` approach in your connection string??

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen your connection string yet - but from your description, it seems it might be this problem here:

the whole *`User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName=`* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MyDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...